# Magento - Product Page 404 with correct product data

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-1.9, data-migration, data-import

I am having a strange issue with a Magento data import and was wondering if anyone else had come across this and had possibly found a solution to help diagnose the problem.

I used the Magento Data Migration Tool to migrate data from a Magento 1 instance to an existing Magento 2 instance. The Magento 2 instance already had some data, so this wasn't a fresh copy of everything, I did it in stages, first the orders only, then the customers only, and finally products and categories. I ignored the CMS blocks and pages as those needed to be kept as well as theme and a few other settings and issues (so I only ran migrate:data).

My config file for the data migration looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_DataMigrationTool:etc/config.xsd">
    <steps mode="data">
        <step title="Data Integrity Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
        </step>
        <step title="EAV Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Eav\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Eav\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Eav\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Inventory Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Inventory\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Inventory\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Inventory\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="PostProcessing Step">
            <data>Migration\Step\PostProcessing\Data</data>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="delta">
        <step title="Map Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Map\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Inventory Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Inventory\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Inventory\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <source>...</source>
    <destination>...</destination>
    <options>...</options>
</config>
```

The product and category data safely copied over and I can see them all in the database as well as in the admin. The URL rewrites also work correctly. However, on some (but not ALL) product pages, it displays almost all the product data except the name, but the page title is 404 and it shows the 404 layout and the 404 content, below all the product data (see image)[image: product 404 issue with product data].

So, unlike most issues where the product pages are 404ing, I know it's not a URL rewrite issue (as the same happens if I use the absolute Magento paths instead of the URL rewrite paths). I had this happen before on another data import test, and when I looked in the db there were products assigned to old attribute sets that no longer existed, so I deleted them, re-indexed and cleared cache and that fixed it.

I have reviewed and confirmed all attribute sets assigned to products are correct. I have re-indexed, cleared cache multiple times. This fixed a few products but not the majority of them. I believe this is happening due to some incorrect/corrupt data in the db relating to products but I have no idea how to diagnose where/where to look. I can't wipe everything and reinstall as there is data we need to keep.

Has anyone come across this issue before and perhaps found a solution or a good way to figure out what bad data is messing this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else who might come across this issue, I figured out the issue. In the data migration I brought over categories, products, and URL rewrites. The URL rewrites were brought over with the right request paths but their IDs were different so somehow they broke the Magento path and pages were all 404ing.

When I went in to a product, changed the URL key to something else, and then changed it back, it regenerated the correct URL rewrite linked up correctly in Magento and the page worked without 404ing.

This is very frustrating especially because in Magento 2 there is no built in way to regenerate product url rewrites. You have to manually drop all URL rewrites and updated and resave products to regenerate them correctly. Interestingly, I did this on another project where the URL rewrites copied over correctly and worked without issue. I verified on this migration that the url_rewrite table was clear and all the values were imported so there is likely issues with the original Magento 1 url_rewrite content on this particular project that caused this issue.